# Public resource notwork in jaxrs application

Tags: java, keycloak, java-security

I have the following security constraints entered in the `web.xml`. My objective is that the OpenApi are in the Public area. However the url-pattern `/api/openapi` does not work and get **error 403**  .But path `/api/B` is working correctly
.I used **wildfly** 18 and **keycloak 7**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <module-name>some module</module-name>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>B Api</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/api</url-pattern>
            <http-method>PATCH</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>CONNECT</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Open Api</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/api/openapi</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>B Api</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/api/B</url-pattern>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>B_MANAGEMENT</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>B Api</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/api/B</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>B Api</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/api/B</url-pattern>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>CONNECT</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>PATCH</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
        <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>B_MANAGEMENT</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Instead of linking a source file please post its contents here (use code formatting to get a nice box for larger contents). Also please elaborate on "does not seem to work" - what do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: after call path /api/openapi get error 403

Comment: Did you try moving the constraint on openapi to the top of your constraint list?

Comment: yes dear thomas and not work !